# Capacitive dropper power supply for LED - zener/decoupling capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, zener, transient, transformerless

Let's say you have a standard capacitive dropper power supply like the following (from Wikipedia):

[image]

I understand that these work well for driving LEDs since they act like a constant current source. I was wondering if the design could be (safely) simplified further by removing the zener and decoupling capacitor - the LEDs don't care what voltage they "see" as they're current-limited anyway, and human eyes cannot detect 120Hz flicker.

I mentioned this to a friend of mine and he pointed out that the mains is subject to voltage transients from things like lightning and inductive loads switching off, and that C2 would shunt the majority of these transients away, protecting the LEDs - that seems to make sense, I suppose C2 + the input impedance of the circuit would behave like an RC filter during a transient?

If that's the case, what purpose does the zener serve if voltage regulation isn't important, and why do so many commercial designs seem to include one? Simulating a similar circuit with a 50us/1kV spike (a la IEC 61000-4-5), the LEDs only see a small increase in voltage and current - C2 does limit the transient significantly...but if C2 were gone, is a sub-millisecond overcurrent even that bad anyway?

Comment: Addendum - I am aware of the dangers posed by the lack of galvanic isolation with this design - this is just a hypothetical.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but for safety, and assuming one is in a country with  a Live/Neutral/Ground mains power system, I would place R1, C1 and R2 all on the Line side of the power. That way, if there should be a ground fault, it won't set my components on fire.

Comment: In designs I've seen before there was a fuse on the line side along with C1 and R2. R1 was on the neutral. With that setup there seems like a low risk of fire due to the fuse, no? Even better I have seen some that use a fusible resistor for R1 instead so I would assume that could be placed on either conductor safely (although it's probably better to fuse the hot I suppose).

Comment: The fault condition that I am concerned about is that some part of your circuit becomes grounded. This creates a parallel pathway for current to return to the mains, through neutral and through ground. _Any_ protective circuitry on the neutral side, including R1 if it were on the neutral side, or a fuse if it were on the neutral side, could thus be potentially bypassed. It is always better to fuse the hot side, or at least I can't think of an occasion where it might be advantageous to do it the other way.

Comment: Good points. In this design R1 is not technically a protective element—it's just for inrush limiting—although I suppose it does sort of become a factor in protection during a transient.

Comment: I still haven't decided whether to attempt an answer regarding removing the cap and "zener" that regulate the output. However, it is worth noting that LEDs can fail "slowly". That is, they may experience temporary currents above their rated absolute maximum and yet still "work" afterward. However, it may be that they LED suffered minor but barely noticable damage. Over time, repetitive pulses like this can lead to the LED becoming dimmer and dimmer. Without knowing the exact LED specs, it is hard to say how much regulation you can safely dispense with.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy how the components are arranged between live and neutral is unimportant. A device with a power supply like that would most likely be contained a plastic box with two prongs sticking out (for example a night light), and it would not have any external connections for safety reasons, so it can be plugged in in any orientation.

Comment: @Justme. Yes, commercial power supplies of this sort are securely contained within an insulating enclosure, and the polarity of the wires doesn't matter, nor where one places the resistors / capacitors etc. However, if an experimenter is creating their own circuit, it might not be so securely insulated. Hence my advice.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy You are right on that. Because it might be connected in any polarity, no part of the circuit is safe to touch, and no part of the circuit is safe to connect to any other piece of equipment like an oscilloscope.

Comment: What about the C2 model in your surge simulation, have you included ESR/ESL? I bet they are going to be the most important in ruling the transient response

Comment: @carloc No, I figured for an aluminum electrolytic these values would be negligible, but I suppose I should reconsider that. What would be the appropriate way to calculate the transient response of C2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that these work well for driving LEDs since they act like a constant current source. I was wondering if the design could be (safely) simplified further by removing the zener and decoupling capacitor

There are plenty of cheap LED lights just like this. They're all unusable for anything except indicator lights because they flicker at 120Hz though.

> In this design R1 is not technically a protective element—it's just for inrush limiting

R1 should be a [fusible resistor](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/fw.pdf), which is cheaper in mass production than a resistor and a fuse. These resistors are designed to fail open just like a fuse.

R2 should be specified to withstand the voltage, which probably means several resistors in series.

> mains is subject to voltage transients from things like lightning and inductive loads switching off, and that C2 would shunt the majority of these transients away, protecting the LEDs - that seems to make sense, I suppose C2 + the input impedance of the circuit would behave like an RC filter during a transient?

If the transient is fast enough, that depends mostly on C2's ESR. LEDs can also tolerate surprisingly high non-repetitive peak currents.

> If that's the case, what purpose does the zener serve if voltage regulation isn't important

For LED lights, I don't see any purpose for it.

When a component absorbs a transient, the transient energy is converted into heat. So its ability to absorb a transient's energy comes from thermal mass of the part of the component where dissipation occurs. A tiny semiconductor junction can absorb much less energy than a bulky voltage-dependent resistor, for example. Unless the zener is much bulkier than the LEDs and rated for high current, it won't have much more transient handling capability.

Comment: Good to know about LEDs handling surge currents, thanks! I did some further simulations with C1 shorted and the LED array failed open and realized the zener comes into play blowing the fuse and protecting C2 from overvoltage, respectively. I've heard fusible resistors are pretty terrible at their job, and reading the datasheet for one seems to confirm this—e.g. a 1W resistor wouldn't actually blow unless it got to 30W or more, which even a dead short on the rectifier + C1 failing short wouldn't generate. Wouldn't a fuse be a safer choice here?

Comment: Fusible resistors have a lot more thermal mass than a fuse, so they are very slow to blow open. But hey, it costs one cent less! Note I'm not sure the zener would survive long enough to blow the fuse...

Comment: In a crude simulation, the zener had to handle (IIRC) ~100W for less than 1/4 of a second. I can probably check the datasheet to confirm this, but I'd imagine a 1.3W zener could probably survive that, no?

Comment: check page 4 of this [datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1SMA5913BT3_D-1101349.pdf) for pulse power... but 1/4s looks like too much.

Comment: My mistake - I completely misremembered. Here's a simulated circuit driving a 32V LED COB at 10mA (3.3k resistor) with a [200mA fuse](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/643/ds-CP-mrf-series-1313120.pdf): https://tinyurl.com/y3l2oejh closing the switch to short the X2, the zener in that datasheet would experience 2-3 65W pulses before the fuse blows. At 1/120=8.3ms, that seems to be comfortably under the .1kW peak pulse power given in that graph, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure, the datasheet uses an exponentially decaying pulse. It's the total dissipated energy that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured out the answer to my question - at least most of it. If the X2 capacitor fails short, the load alone may not draw enough current to blow a fuse - although it may draw enough for itself or R1 to become a fire hazard. The zener clamps enough current to blow the line fuse quickly.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe. I tend to think that the regulation, if it is used with LEDs, is more to reduce the maximum current experienced by the LEDs, and perhaps by so doing, allow them to have a higher average current. But I'm not convinced of that either, because the cost of a slightly more robust LED may be less than the cost of the "zener" and cap. Now if this supply were used with a string of LEDs, the cost of the zener and cap may be less than the cost of multiple more robust LEDs.

Comment: Yeah - I'm thinking LED COBs mostly rather than individual LEDs. The zener would also prevent C2 from exploding due to overvoltage if the LEDs go open-circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The zener is there to provide regulation, since it is a circuit for a capacitive 5V regulated power supply, not a circuit optimized for driving LEDs.

Further down in the article, a circuit that drives LEDs is analyzed, which does not have all the parts as the circuit above.

So for LEDs you can simplify the power supply even further.

But saying that human eyes can't detect the 120 (or 100) Hz flicker of LEDs that are run without a capacitor, that is simply wrong thing to assume. Many people do, some are more sensitive to see it than others, even if you don't see it at all.

Comment: I just picked the image from Wikipedia as an example and because I figured I'd be okay to re-post it here. If you look up schematics for them, or read application notes for designing one, nearly all seem to say to use a zener and decoupling capacitor, but don't really go into the "why" beyond voltage stability—they certainly don't touch on safety, transient suppression, or anything else, which are the things that I was curious about.

Comment: Well it would be nice if you said which application notes. If it is the appnote from Microchip, you can be pretty sure it is made to support people powering up Microchip products like microcontrollers which do need regulated supplies.